# Concurrently reading numpy arrays in parallel

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, parallel-processing, python-multiprocessing

Consider the following:

```
fine = np.random.uniform(0,100,10)
fine[fine<20] = 0 # introduce some intermittency
coarse = np.sum(fine.reshape(-1,2),axis=1)
```

`fine` is a timeseries of magnitudes (e.g. volume of rainfall). `coarse` is the same timeseries but at a halved resolution, so every 2 timesteps in `fine` are aggregated to a single value in `coarse`.

I am then interested in the weighting that determines the proportions of the magnitude of `coarse` that corresponds to each timestep in `fine` for the instances where the value of `coarse` is above zero.

```
def w_xx(fine, coarse):
    weights = [] 
    for i, val in enumerate(coarse):
        if val > 0:
            w = fine[i*2:i*2+2]/val # returns both w1 and w2, w1 is 1st element, w2 = 1-w1 is second
            weights.append(w)
    return np.asarray(weights)
```

So `w_xx(fine,coarse)` would return an array of shape `5,2` where the elements of `axis=1` are the weights of `fine` for a value of `coarse`.

This is all fine for smaller timeseries, but I'm running this analysis on ~60k-sized arrays of `fine`, plus in a loop of 300+ iterations.

I have been trying to make this run in parallel using the `multiprocessing` library in Python2.7 but I've not managed to get far. I need to be be reading both timeseries at the same time in order to get the corresponding values of `fine` for every value in `coarse`, plus to only work for values above 0, which is what my analysis requires.

I would appreciate suggestions on a better way to do this. I imagine if I can define a mapping function to use with `Pool.map` in `multiprocessing`, I should be able to parallelize this? I've only just started out with `multiprocessing` so I don't know if there is another way?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve the same result in a vectorized form by simply doing:

```
>>> (fine / np.repeat(coarse, 2)).reshape(-1, 2)
```

then you may filter out rows which `coarse` is zero, by using `np.isfinite` since if `coarse` is zero the output is either `inf` or `nan`.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the NumPy expression proposed by @behzad.nouri, you can use the [Pythran](http://pythran.readthedocs.io) compiler to reap extra speedups:

```
$ cat w_xx.py
#pythran export w_xx(float[], float[])
import numpy as np

def w_xx(fine, coarse):
    w = (fine / np.repeat(coarse, 2))
    return w[np.isfinite(w)].reshape(-1, 2)
$ python -m timeit -s 'import numpy as np; fine = np.random.uniform(0, 100, 100000); fine[fine<20] = 0; coarse = np.sum(fine.reshape(-1, 2), axis=1); from w_xx import w_xx' 'w_xx(fine, coarse)'
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.5 msec per loop
$ pythran w_xx.py -fopenmp -march=native # yes, this generates parallel code
$ python -m timeit -s 'import numpy as np; fine = np.random.uniform(0, 100, 100000); fine[fine<20] = 0; coarse = np.sum(fine.reshape(-1, 2), axis=1); from w_xx import w_xx' 'w_xx(fine, coarse)'
1000 loops, best of 3: 867 usec per loop
```

*Disclaimer: I am a Pythran dev.*

Answer (score 0):

Excellent! I didn't know about `np.repeat`, thank you very much.

To answer my original question in the form it was presented, I've then also managed to make this work with `multiprocessing`:

```
import numpy as np    
from multiprocessing import Pool

fine = np.random.uniform(0,100,100000)
fine[fine<20] = 0
coarse = np.sum(fine.reshape(-1,2),axis=1)

def wfunc(zipped):
   return zipped[0]/zipped[1]

def wpar(zipped, processes):
    p = Pool(processes)
    calc = np.asarray(p.map(wfunc, zip(fine,np.repeat(coarse,2))))

    p.close()
    p.join()

    return calc[np.isfinite(calc)].reshape(-1,2)
```

However, the suggestion by @behzad.nouri is evidently better:

```
def w_opt(fine, coarse):
    w = (fine / np.repeat(coarse, 2))
    return w[np.isfinite(w)].reshape(-1,2)    

#using some iPython magic
%timeit w_opt(fine,coarse)
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.88 ms per loop

%timeit w_xx(fine,coarse)
1 loops, best of 3: 342 ms per loop

%timeit wpar(zip(fine,np.repeat(coarse,2)),6) #I've 6 cores at my disposal
1 loops, best of 3: 1.76 s per loop
```

Thanks again!